# Ripple emulator chrome plugin is taking long time to execute

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-extension, ripple

I was using [Ripple](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/) Chrome extension for test running my phonegap apps, and I did all [settings for Ripple](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-ripple.git;a=blob;f=doc/chrome_extension.md;h=a32afd09d0e39e9c79d439078cea5ba8e602c021;hb=HEAD), like making a Chrome shortcut with `--allow-file-access-from-files` and in Chrome extension list checking "allow local file access" for Ripple.

On running my HTML file which I made for phonegap build, Chrome is taking a good time to deliver a response. Everything is working, the only issue is the delay on response.

I tried on another desktop, and there it is quiet and fast. I re-installed the extension and restarted Chrome and OS a couple of times to no effect.

Comment: There is a relatively recent [Web Store version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/details) of the Ripple extension, are you using that, or are you building it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

For your information, I had similar issues when using Chrome. Make sure Chrome isn't running in the background when you close it. Since a few versions of Chrome, this is enabled by default. Check your taskbar to see if this is the case.
If Chrome is indeed running in the background, right-click on the chrome-icon in the taskbar and disable "running in background". This worked for me and now Ripple fires superfast.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to confirm your system spec. development workstations are known to be resource demanding, particularly the RAM,  and processors. if your app was faster on another system, you might want to check that system's spec also and compare with yours.